# REST API is disabled in janus

Tags: rest, webrtc, janus-gateway

[image]

As you can see REST is disabled by default when i run

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/janus

I want REST to be enable how to enable it?

> ./configure --help | grep -i rest

[image]

Comment: What does `./configure --help | grep -i rest` show?

Comment: I just added a screenshot for that too. could you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libmicrohttpd was not installed.(Because its outdated. janus-gateway needs libmicrohttpd not libmicrohttpd-dev. most of the installation guides recommends to install libmicrohttpd-dev.)

So i had to install the below libmicrohttpd from gnu and now its working perfectly

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libmicrohttpd/libmicrohttpd-0.9.59.tar.gz 
tar xvf libmicrohttpd-0.9.59.tar.gz 
cd libmicrohttpd-0.9.59 
./configure 
make 
sudo make install 
sudo ldconfig
```